# Symfony: setter injection not working in a custom Doctrine filter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

To make sure that every user gets only data that belongs to its account, I tried to create a doctrine filter that inject Security service to it using a setter (setSecurity) and #[Required] attribute, and then in addFilterConstraint method, I get the user and create needed constraint SQL, but unfortunately for some reason setter injection not working and setSecurity never executed!

I'm using Symfony 6.3.4

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Filter;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\Attribute\Required;

class AccountFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    private ?Security $security = null;

    #[Required]
    public function setSecurity(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias): string
    {
        // check if the entity has the account field
        if (!$targetEntity->hasAssociation('account')) {
            return '';
        }

        $accountColumnName = $targetEntity->getSingleAssociationJoinColumnName('account');

        if ($this->security === null) {
            return '';
        }

        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf('%s.%s = %s', $targetTableAlias, $accountColumnName, $user->getAccount()->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply inject in constructor ?

Comment: @Skuti SQLFilter uses final constructor, and final methods including constructors cannot be overridden in child classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please see Az.Youness' answer, it is better.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77190383/4275413)

Sadly, the [FilterCollection](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/099e51d8990c586778c564a9ed1eaa6401f2bc83/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/FilterCollection.php#L18) that handles filters and that is instantiated by probably doctrine only receives the class names of the filter and [instantiates it when enabled](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/099e51d8990c586778c564a9ed1eaa6401f2bc83/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/FilterCollection.php#L102) (which probably happens automatically).

Since as far as I know doctrine and symfony only use *one* entity manager, and apparently the filter collection is kept between queries, you might be able to inject your Security by getting your filter from the entitymanager in a kernel event listener (where you can request the Security service via standard dependency injection) or some other way and setSecurity explicitly then.

```php
$entityManager->getFilters()->getFilter("the filter name")->setSecurity($security);
```

**However**, when the filter is *disabled*, it will be removed completely and instantiated again when *enabled* again, according to [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/e9537f4cdef6fd5a6d3990811025770a48ed726d/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/FilterCollection.php#L153). You would have to use [suspend/restore](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/filters.html#suspending-restoring-filters) instead, if you ever want to "disable" the filter for a number of queries. Which might be relevant for you or not.

Comment: This is what I understand from your answer which I think is the right one. 
The FilterCollection class is responsible for managing the filters in Doctrine, does not use dependency injection to create the filter instances, but rather uses the class names that are registred in the doctrine config file.

Comment: ...and for the workaround I think it might be better option to use filter parameters than manually injecting the security service into the filter, as it would be more consistent with Doctrine ORM design and avoid potential issues with the filter lifecycle.

Comment: That sounds better than my workaround, kind of. Why don't you write down your solution, it sounds interesting ;o) Don't care about the reputation or whatever ;o)

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround solution that I came up with based on @Jakumi’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77184913/2432219):

So, instead of trying to inject the Security service into the filter class, we can create a request event listener that enables the filter if necessary:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

#[AsEventListener(event: RequestEvent::class)]
class AccountFilterEnablerListener
{
    public function __construct(
        private Security $security,
        private EntityManagerInterface $em,
    ) {
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (null === $user = $this->security->getUser()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $this->em->getFilters()->enable('account_filter')->setParameter('account', $user->getAccount()->getId());
    }
}
```

and AccountFilter class will look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Filter;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class AccountFilter extends SQLFilter
{

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias): string
    {
        // check if the entity has an account field
        if (!$targetEntity->hasAssociation('account')) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf(
           '%s.%s = %s',
           $targetTableAlias,
           $targetEntity->getSingleAssociationJoinColumnName('account'), // account_id
           $this->getParameter('account')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems indeed more appropriate, happy to have provided a direction. mark it as your answer when you can.